# how to dynamically sort elements using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Data looks like:

```
{
    "createdAt": 1424306663000,
    "updatedAt": null,
    "id": 5098,
    "importSource": null,
    "importRef": null,
    "site": "fijiwater",
    "siteCode": "fijiwater",
    "bannerImageMobile": {
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "id": null,
        "importSource": null,
        "importRef": null,
        "type": "IMAGE",
        "ref": "fijiwater/images/mobile-hero-final.jpg",
        "ordinal": 1,
        "primary": null,
        "meta": null,
        "dimension": null
    },
    "bannerImage": {
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "id": null,
        "importSource": null,
        "importRef": null,
        "type": "IMAGE",
        "ref": "fijiwater/images/extras-bg-final.jpg",
        "ordinal": 1,
        "primary": null,
        "meta": null,
        "dimension": null
    },
    "name": "Extras",
    "displayName": "Extras",
    "vanityUrl": "extras",
    "about": null,
    "products": [
        {
            "createdAt": 1422317527000,
            "updatedAt": null,
            "id": 1662224,
            "importSource": null,
            "importRef": null,
            "name": "The FIJI Water Straw (6pk)",
            "code": null,
            "defaultPriceInCents": 995,
            "specializedPriceInCents": null,
            "msrpInCents": 995,
            "subscriptionPrice": 0,
            "ordinal": 0,
            "tagLine": null,
            "mainImage": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "id": 178361,
                "importSource": null,
                "importRef": null,
                "type": "IMAGE",
                "ref": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736511908_6pack_straw_image_1.400w.jpg",
                "ordinal": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "meta": [
                    {
                        "createdAt": null,
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "id": null,
                        "importSource": null,
                        "importRef": null,
                        "key": "medium",
                        "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736511908_6pack_straw_image_1.400w.jpg",
                        "displayValue": null,
                        "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                        "keyDescription": "location of medium sized image",
                        "site": null,
                        "priority": null
                    },
                    {
                        "createdAt": null,
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "id": null,
                        "importSource": null,
                        "importRef": null,
                        "key": "large",
                        "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736511908_6pack_straw_image_1.400w.jpg",
                        "displayValue": null,
                        "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                        "keyDescription": "location of large sized image",
                        "site": null,
                        "priority": null
                    }
                        ],
                "dimension": null
            },
            "vendorSku": null,
            "globalSku": null,
            "cost": 0,
            "maxPrice": 995,
            "minPrice": 995
    }, {
            "createdAt": 1422317651000,
            "updatedAt": null,
            "id": 1662226,
            "importSource": null,
            "importRef": null,
            "name": "500ML SILVER SLEEVE",
            "code": null,
            "defaultPriceInCents": 2000,
            "specializedPriceInCents": null,
            "msrpInCents": 2000,
            "subscriptionPrice": 0,
            "ordinal": 1,
            "tagLine": null,
            "mainImage": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "id": 178365,
                "importSource": null,
                "importRef": null,
                "type": "IMAGE",
                "ref": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736626348_fiji-silver-sleeve-500ml_400x400.400w.jpg",
                "ordinal": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "meta": [{
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "medium",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736626348_fiji-silver-sleeve-500ml_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of medium sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }, {
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "large",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736626348_fiji-silver-sleeve-500ml_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of large sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }],
                "dimension": null
            },
            "vendorSku": null,
            "globalSku": null,
            "cost": 0,
            "maxPrice": 2000,
            "minPrice": 2000
    }, {
            "createdAt": 1422317682000,
            "updatedAt": null,
            "id": 1662227,
            "importSource": null,
            "importRef": null,
            "name": "1.0L SILVER SLEEVE",
            "code": null,
            "defaultPriceInCents": 3000,
            "specializedPriceInCents": null,
            "msrpInCents": 3000,
            "subscriptionPrice": 0,
            "ordinal": 2,
            "tagLine": null,
            "mainImage": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "id": 178364,
                "importSource": null,
                "importRef": null,
                "type": "IMAGE",
                "ref": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736611071_fiji-silver-sleeve-1l_400x400.400w.jpg",
                "ordinal": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "meta": [{
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "medium",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736611071_fiji-silver-sleeve-1l_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of medium sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }, {
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "large",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736611071_fiji-silver-sleeve-1l_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of large sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }],
                "dimension": null
            },
            "vendorSku": null,
            "globalSku": null,
            "cost": 0,
            "maxPrice": 3000,
            "minPrice": 3000
    }, {
            "createdAt": 1422317711000,
            "updatedAt": null,
            "id": 1662228,
            "importSource": null,
            "importRef": null,
            "name": "500ML SILVER BAMBOO SLEEVE",
            "code": null,
            "defaultPriceInCents": 2500,
            "specializedPriceInCents": null,
            "msrpInCents": 2500,
            "subscriptionPrice": 0,
            "ordinal": 3,
            "tagLine": null,
            "mainImage": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "id": 178363,
                "importSource": null,
                "importRef": null,
                "type": "IMAGE",
                "ref": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736598667_fiji-silver-sleeve-bamboo-500ml_400x400.400w.jpg",
                "ordinal": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "meta": [{
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "medium",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736598667_fiji-silver-sleeve-bamboo-500ml_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of medium sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }, {
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "large",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736598667_fiji-silver-sleeve-bamboo-500ml_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of large sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }],
                "dimension": null
            },
            "vendorSku": null,
            "globalSku": null,
            "cost": 0,
            "maxPrice": 2500,
            "minPrice": 2500
    }, {
            "createdAt": 1422317755000,
            "updatedAt": null,
            "id": 1662229,
            "importSource": null,
            "importRef": null,
            "name": "1.0L SILVER BAMBOO SLEEVE",
            "code": null,
            "defaultPriceInCents": 3500,
            "specializedPriceInCents": null,
            "msrpInCents": 3500,
            "subscriptionPrice": 0,
            "ordinal": 4,
            "tagLine": null,
            "mainImage": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "id": 178362,
                "importSource": null,
                "importRef": null,
                "type": "IMAGE",
                "ref": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736585411_fiji-silver-sleeve-bamboo-1l_400x400.400w.jpg",
                "ordinal": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "meta": [{
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "medium",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736585411_fiji-silver-sleeve-bamboo-1l_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of medium sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }, {
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "large",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424736585411_fiji-silver-sleeve-bamboo-1l_400x400.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of large sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }],
                "dimension": null
            },
            "vendorSku": null,
            "globalSku": null,
            "cost": 0,
            "maxPrice": 3500,
            "minPrice": 3500
    }, {
            "createdAt": 1422317802000,
            "updatedAt": null,
            "id": 1662230,
            "importSource": null,
            "importRef": null,
            "name": "FIJI WATER CUFFLINKS",
            "code": null,
            "defaultPriceInCents": 3000,
            "specializedPriceInCents": null,
            "msrpInCents": 3000,
            "subscriptionPrice": 0,
            "ordinal": 5,
            "tagLine": null,
            "mainImage": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "id": 178402,
                "importSource": null,
                "importRef": null,
                "type": "IMAGE",
                "ref": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424816861861_FIJI-Cufflinks.400w.jpg",
                "ordinal": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "meta": [{
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "medium",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424816861861_FIJI-Cufflinks.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of medium sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }, {
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "id": null,
                    "importSource": null,
                    "importRef": null,
                    "key": "large",
                    "value": "//image-cdn.symphonycommerce.com/images/sites/fijiwater/1424816861861_FIJI-Cufflinks.400w.jpg",
                    "displayValue": null,
                    "keyType": "IMAGE_SIZE",
                    "keyDescription": "location of large sized image",
                    "site": null,
                    "priority": null
            }],
                "dimension": null
            },
            "vendorSku": null,
            "globalSku": null,
            "cost": 0,
            "maxPrice": 3000,
            "minPrice": 3000
    }],
    "removedProducts": [],
    "addedProducts": [],
    "productCount": 6,
    "subCategories": [],
    "priority": 17,
    "tags": null,
    "pageTitle": "Bottled Water Accessories | FIJI Water",
    "extraInfo": "Purchase FIJI Water Accessories ranging from Signature Silver Sleeves to FIJI Water Car Cup Holders. Accessorize your FIJI Water today!",
    "state": "NON_PUBLISHED",
    "parentId": null,
    "url": "/extras"
}
```

My view looks like

```
<div id="banner" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + preLink + data.bannerImage.ref + ')'}" style="background-size: 100% 100%;      background-repeat: no-repeat; ">

    <div id="proLink">
        <a href="#productList">Product List</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bannerText">
        <h2>It's slim, trim and ready for the gym.</h2>
        <p>Our sleek 700mL bottle fits everywhere. </p>
        <p>Cupholders, treadmills, your lifestyle.</p>
    </div>

</div>
<a name="productList"></a>
<div id="extras">
   <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
   <div id="center">
       <div id="products" ng-repeat="p in data.products|orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
        <div id="product">
            <p>{{p.defaultPriceInCents/100 | currency}}</p>
            <img ng-src="{{p.mainImage.ref}}" alt="">
            <h3>{{p.name}}</h3>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my module and controller looks like:

```
angular.module("myApp.products", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/products', {
                controller: 'ProductsController',
                templateUrl: 'products/products.html'
            })
            .when('/products/:productId', {
                controller: 'ProductDetailsController',
                templateUrl: 'products/product-details.html'
            });
    }])
    .controller('ProductsController', ['$scope', 'fileInfo', function ($scope, fileInfo) {
        $scope.preLink = "http://sneakpeeq-sites.s3.amazonaws.com/";
        fileInfo
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.data = data;
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                return data;
            });

        $scope.sortType = 'defaultPriceInCents'; // set the default sort type
        $scope.sortReverse = false; // set the default sort order
        $scope.searchFish = ''; // set the default search/filter term
    }]);
```

I want to have a dropdown that have these two values:

- Price
- name

and when some one selects one of them I want to sort the elements accordingly in ascending or descending order. Can someone help please.

Comment: Even docs have example of it. Very easy.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find it. I will look again. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy this have sorting example. in your case you need to take sorting predicate from select box, bound to some model which will be used in `ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:yourModel"`